# Combining dictionary with possibly repeated keys into another dictionary containing the largest values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to perform a "Maximum" operation in two (or possibly more) dictionaries, which would generate a new dictionary as follows:

- If a key is present only in some of the dictionaries, it's value is included in the result;
- If a key is present in *more than one* of the dictionaries, the *largest* value is included in the result;

Is there a way to do this using Linq? I can only think of iterating over all the keys of every dictionary, and feels very ugly.

Besides, this feels like the sort of thing Linq would be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can merge the dictionaries into one lookup, and than transform it back to dictionary.

```
var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                         .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max());
```